# How to export Prometheus to Google Cloud Monitoring using OpenTelemetry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-cloud-monitoring, open-telemetry

We have an ASGI api (FastAPI), in this API we have a metrics Prometheus endpoint. How to export these metrics to Google Cloud Monitoring using OpenTelemetry. Not using a sidecar.

Comment: Do you run on K8S your app?

Comment: No, just Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export your Open Telemetry metrics to Cloud Monitoring, Prometheus is useless, you can use directly Open Telemetry - CLoud Monitoring integration.

In python, you have an Open Telemetry exporter that allow you to do that. No side car.

Then, if you need to query your metrics with PromQL, you can use [Managed Services for Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus) that offer a compliant PromQL endpoint and based on Monarch (Google internal logging system)

Answer (score 0):

OpenTelemetry doesn't really have a way to scrape a Prometheus endpoint that I'm aware of.  I would recommend simply using the Prometheus/Cloud Monitoring integration if that's at all an option.  Otherwise, you can instrument your application to write to Cloud Monitoring using OpenTelemetry.

Comment: In order to use this, do I need to have a side car, correct?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find how to. But would you have any recommendations in how to export this endpoint metrics , as it already exists, to Google Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: Actually, some OTEL collectors offer Prometheus, e.g. https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/components/prometheus-exporters . You need to configure Prometheus receiver https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/prometheusreceiver to scrape metrics and remote write Prometheus exporter https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusremotewriteexporter to push

Comment: @JanGaraj do you have any github example ? I would like to add a sidecar to my pod that run an OTEL collector that scrape prometheus endpoint ( prometehus receiver ) and send metrics to gcp with googlecloudexporter

Comment: @raphaelauv see readme https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15983 - AWS OTEL collector is scraping own perf metrics and pushing them to the AWS Prometheus.

Comment: @JanGaraj thanks , I found my way , it work perfectly with the container

otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.48.0

Thanks again for your previous message :+1